# iPhone application - pop up dialogue - sort of

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

I have an iPhone application which is, in essence, a list. There is a UINavigationBar at the top, and then there is a UITableView which holds the list. I'd like to have an option in some way or another of allowing the user to sort the list in different ways. So, in my mind, I picture having a NavigationItem on the UINavigationBar that, when touched, a little pop up dialogue comes up. You select the "sort" you want, a check mark appears next to it, and the dialogue goes away.

I'm not really sure how to do this. I tried creating a UIView, adding a UIViewController onto it (which held this list of different "sort" parameters (ex. sort alphabetically, sort by date, etc) in a UITableView. **But the UITableView isn't responding to any touches, and I'm not sure why.**

Does anyone have an idea for using Apples wonderful interface for having an option like this? I can't use a UISegmentedControl below the UINavigationBar, because there are 5 possible options, and I can't fit all that in a single UISegmentedControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview). You could just slide one up from the bottom of the view whenever that button is pressed. I've done this in the past and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into `UIActionSheet` at all? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactionsheet

It seems like it might be a good fit for this approach. The action sheet will be a bit tall since you will have 5-6 buttons in it, but it should get the job done and they are really easy to implement.

The way you are approaching it with displaying another view with its own UITableView in it would work also, but it doesn't seem like the best approach to me. Granted, if you are set on going with that approach, provide us with some code so we can try to figure out why the `UITableView` isn't responding to touches.

Comment: how could I make a UIActionSheet without a destructive button?

Comment: Via the docs, 'Specify nil if you do not want a destructive button.'

Answer (score 0):

You won't get a checkmark, but if you want a pop-up I suggest using a UIAlertView.